# CSS positioning helper tips icon

Tags: html, css

Good Morning,

I have this line of code:

```
<div class="navigation">
<a href="~/Uploads/TimeSlotTemplate.xlsx" download>Download Upload Template</a> <div class="help-tip"> <p>This is the inline help tip! You can explain to your users what this section of your web app is about.</p></div>
<a href="~/Uploads/TimeSlotTemplate.xlsx" download>Download Upload Template</a> <div class="help-tip"> <p>This is the inline help tip! You can explain to your users what this section of your web app is about.</p></div></div>
```

What I am trying to do is have the help-tip div go right next to the link. The paragraph appears when you put your mouse over the help-tip div. I am looking to get the paragraph to go directly under the help-tip icon in short of an overlay style. When I remove the position absolute for the both elements the icon goes right next to the icon and the paragraph goes under the icon, but it creates a massive amount of space.

Here is my css

```
.help-tip{
    position: absolute;
    top: 18px;
    right: 18px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #BCDBEA;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 26px;
    cursor: default;
}

.help-tip:before{
    content:'?';
    font-weight: bold;
    color:#fff;
}

.help-tip:hover p{
    display:block;
    transform-origin: 100% 0%;

    -webkit-animation: fadeIn 0.3s ease-in-out;
    animation: fadeIn 0.3s ease-in-out;

}

.help-tip p{    /* The tooltip */
    display: none;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #1E2021;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 300px;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    right: -4px;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 1.4;
}

.help-tip p:before{ /* The pointer of the tooltip */
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    width:0;
    height: 0;
    border:6px solid transparent;
    border-bottom-color:#1E2021;
    right:10px;
    top:-12px;
}

.help-tip p:after{ /* Prevents the tooltip from being hidden */
    width:100%;
    height:40px;
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    top:-40px;
    left:0;
}

/* CSS animation */

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
    0% { 
        opacity:0; 
        transform: scale(0.6);
    }

    100% {
        opacity:100%;
        transform: scale(1);
    }
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
    0% { opacity:0; }
    100% { opacity:100%; }
}
```

and here is a jfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/13275tvz/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need some HTML and CSS Fix

When you are making the element position absolute, make sure it's parent have the position relative property.

HTML

```
<div class="navigation">
<div class="link-container">
<a href="~/Uploads/TimeSlotTemplate.xlsx" download>Download Upload Template</a> <div class="help-tip"> <p>This is the inline help tip! You can explain to your users what this section of your web app is about.</p></div>
</div>

<div class="link-container">

<a href="~/Uploads/TimeSlotTemplate.xlsx" download>Download Upload Template</a> <div class="help-tip"> <p>This is the inline help tip! You can explain to your users what this section of your web app is about.</p></div></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.help-tip{
    position: absolute;
    top: 18px;
    right: 18px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #BCDBEA;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 26px;
    cursor: default;
}
.link-container{
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
}
.help-tip:before{
    content:'?';
    font-weight: bold;
    color:#fff;
}

.help-tip:hover p{
    display:block;
    transform-origin: 100% 0%;

    -webkit-animation: fadeIn 0.3s ease-in-out;
    animation: fadeIn 0.3s ease-in-out;

}

.help-tip p{    /* The tooltip */
    display: none;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #1E2021;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 300px;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    right: -4px;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 1.4;
}

.help-tip p:before{ /* The pointer of the tooltip */
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    width:0;
    height: 0;
    border:6px solid transparent;
    border-bottom-color:#1E2021;
    right:10px;
    top:-12px;
}

.help-tip p:after{ /* Prevents the tooltip from being hidden */
    width:100%;
    height:40px;
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    top:-40px;
    left:0;
}

/* CSS animation */

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
    0% { 
        opacity:0; 
        transform: scale(0.6);
    }

    100% {
        opacity:100%;
        transform: scale(1);
    }
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
    0% { opacity:0; }
    100% { opacity:100%; }
}
```

Style Accordingly..

[Link for reference](https://jsfiddle.net/DChandraShekhar/13275tvz/2/)

hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

you need change position to relative, display to inline-block and desmiss top, right.

```
.help-tip {
    position: relative;
    /* top: 18px; */
    /* right: 18px; */
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #BCDBEA;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 26px;
    cursor: default;
    display: inline-block;
}
```